# Does collapsing intersections to a point preserve local contractibility?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Suppose I have closed sets $K_1$ and $K_2$ which are locally contractible and intersect non-trivially. Can I guarantee that $K_1/(K_1 \cap K_2)$ is locally contractible?

Is it false for merely closed sets but true for compact sets? If it is false, are there some nice assumptions under which it is true? Thanks in advance!